# ImportError: No module named genpy

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am very new to ROS as I just started installing it on my Ubuntu 16.4 (I am fully aware that there hasn't been a version of ROS released for Ubuntu 16.4.) but so far all my installation went smoothly except when I tried to run the 'rostopic' line it gives me:

"Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/bin/rostopic", line 34, in 
import rostopic

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostopic/**init**.py", line 59, in 
import genpy

ImportError: No module named genpy"

Anyone can tell me how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236070/importerror:-no-module-named-genpy/) by [Ghadeer](https://answers.ros.org/users/27071/ghadeer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem, but only because I did not complete installation instructions.
Setting up environment correctly  ( $ source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash ) fixed this.

---

Originally posted by [Max Kiva](https://answers.ros.org/users/31584/max-kiva/) with karma: 16 on 2017-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0